# Firebase Realtime Database Making Snapshot Value Friendly

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database SDK in a TypeScript + Express server to create a Rest API backend. I got a React frontend which uses axios to get that data from the API endpoints. But, whenever I have to iterate child properties I get also a headache.

So I created a really bad code to convert these Firebase [snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) into friendly (or what I think is friendly) readable and iterable objects.

This is the code:

```js
const form = snapshot.val();
form.id = snapshot.key;
form.steps = Object.keys(form.steps).map(stepKey => {
    form.steps[stepKey].id = stepKey;
    form.steps[stepKey].inputs = Object.keys(form.steps[stepKey].inputs).map(inputKey => {
        form.steps[stepKey].inputs[inputKey].id = inputKey;
        if (form.steps[stepKey].inputs[inputKey].conditions) {
            form.steps[stepKey].inputs[inputKey].conditions = Object.keys(form.steps[stepKey].inputs[inputKey].conditions).map(conditionKey => {
                form.steps[stepKey].inputs[inputKey].conditions[conditionKey].id = conditionKey;
                return form.steps[stepKey].inputs[inputKey].conditions[conditionKey];
            });
        }
        return form.steps[stepKey].inputs[inputKey];
    });
    return form.steps[stepKey];
});

result.data = form as Form;
```

I know it is bad, but now I get (again, what I think it is) a readable object with children array content to iterate, and also I can think of a way to make a function to do this dynamically.

```json
"data": {
    "author": "my@email.com",
    "created": "2020-12-14T00:04:57.205Z",
    "description": "test form",
    "steps": [
        {
            "description": "test step",
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "helper": "",
                    "inputId": "-MNpzudIoPnBezm4D9sG",
                    "label": "input 1",
                    "id": "-MOTZ7FOiffGLTKXPgyG"
                }
            ],
            "position": 1,
            "title": "First Step",
            "id": "-MOTZ7FPzQaJ94NrZtAP"
        }
    ],
    "title": "A Test Form",
    "id": "-MOTZ7FQ0v-tCs_sEAe2"
}
```

Instead of the original content (`snapshot.val()`):

```json
"data": {
    "author": "my@email.com",
    "created": "2020-12-14T00:04:57.205Z",
    "description": "test form",
    "steps": {
        "-MOTZ7FPzQaJ94NrZtAP": {
            "description": "test step",
            "inputs": {
                "-MOTZ7FOiffGLTKXPgyG": {
                    "helper": "",
                    "inputId": "-MNpzudIoPnBezm4D9sG",
                    "label": "input 1"
                }
            },
            "position": 1,
            "title": "First Step"
        }
    },
    "title": "A Testing Form"
}
```

So I was thinking of a recursive function which would iterate the `snapshot` with [snapshot.forEach()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#foreach) and every time it [hasChildren()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#haschildren) attach the `snapshot.key` as the `id` and then maybe returning the `snapshot.val()`. But I am not really interested on "reinventing the wheel".

Is that bad code above solving my issue or I should I try a different solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over child snapshots, use the built-in `DataSnapshot.forEach()` operation.

So instead of:

```
form.steps = Object.keys(form.steps).map(stepKey => {
    form.steps[stepKey].id = stepKey;
    ...
});
```

You'd do:

```
snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    form.steps.push({
      id: child.key,
      ...child.val();
    });
    ...
});
```

Comment: Hey Frank, I was not able to answer before since I was working on another stuff. It works for the first iteration (`form.steps`), but it does not satisfy the inputs and so on. I will check it as the right answer anyway. Since its very important for you to get that rep. Thanks for the answer, I will keep reading about how to implement this for the further children properties.